# How do I select records between two date & times?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. `client (client_id, client_name, client_lname)` and `orders(Order_Id,Client_Id,Total_Amount,Order_Date,Order_Time,Order_Status)`
**type of Order_Date amd Order_Time is varchar.**
I have to display records between two dates and times.
I have wrote this query :

```
SELECT 
  o.Order_Id, 
  c.client_name, 
  c.client_lname, 
  o.Total_Amount, 
  o.Order_Date, 
  o.Order_Time 
FROM orders AS o 
JOIN client AS c 
  ON o.Client_id = c.Client_id 
WHERE  (o.Order_Date between '01/01/2013' and '22/01/2013' ) 
AND (o.Order_Time between '17:41:59' and '20:42:04') 
AND o.Order_Status='1' 
ORDER BY o.Order_Id
```

for ex:

```
 Order_id   Client_id   Total_Amount             Order_Date        Order_Time Order_Status
    120        32        60                        01/01/2013        12:44:15    1
121        32        60                        01/01/2013        12:47:51    1
122        32        90                        01/01/2013        18:16:41    1
127        32        60                        01/01/2013        18:34:31    1
128        32        90                        01/01/2013        18:35:19    1
129        32       120                        19/01/2013        8:12:04     1
130        32        90                        19/01/2013        15:33:16    0
131        33        90                        19/01/2013        15:40:03    1
```

I want to display record from 01/01/2013  12:40:00 to 19/01/2013 09:00:00 .So it should display 6 records .what query is to be written

Comment: MYSQL default date format is YYYY-MM-DD. Does that have anything to do with your issue? What error is being returned?

Comment: no I dont have problem with date format .I have kept date & time seperately, I have problem with fetching of record according to time

Comment: please post the results of `DESCRIBE client` and `DESCRIBE orders`

Comment: Shilpa - We need to know the type of the columns, so that we know whether we are dealing with text fields or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I changed the type to

**Order_Date to date and Order_Time to time.**

Then I wrote this query

```
select o.Order_Id,c.client_name,c.client_lname,o.Total_Amount,o.Order_Date,o.Order_Time from orders as o join client as c on o.Client_id=c.Client_id where  DATE_ADD(o.Order_Date, INTERVAL o.Order_Time HOUR_SECOND) BETWEEN '2012-12-03 11:06:54' AND '2013-01-19 01:07:10'  and o.Order_Status='1' order by o.Order_Id
```

It worked. That is what, I was expecting the result.
Thanks everyone for helping me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine date and time columns in your WHERE clause.

```
WHERE DATE_ADD(o.Order_Date, INTERVAL o.Order_Time HOUR_SECOND) 
  BETWEEN '2010-01-01 16:30:00' AND '2010-01-02 17:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following format for your dates:
`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` i.e. `'01/01/2013'` becomes `'2013-01-01 00:00:00'`

[For more info see](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)